# How to receive data from another server (like push notification)

Tags: javascript, php

When a user scans QR code in our web page and makes purchase with it (using a 3rd party application), I want to hide that QR code and process the purchase.

I got an API to check whether the transaction was successful or not. My first thought was sending a request to that API every 2 seconds to check the transaction (terrible idea?). But they told us to create something called a "hook" and they would subscribe to it. What's that? How should I implement that?

Comment: http://resthooks.org/

Comment: We can use webhooks can say callbacks from another server.

Answer (score 2):

Hook may generally mean webhook, here is the wikipedia description.

> Webhooks are "user-defined HTTP callbacks". They are usually triggered
>   by some event, such as pushing code to a repository or a comment being
>   posted to a blog. When that event occurs, the source site makes an
>   HTTP request to the URI configured for the webhook.

[Hook/Webhook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webhook)

Think a hook as an endpoint, where a user can notify you / giving you information.

The way it work is like a user accessing a url and sending params

```
your-url.com/hook?order_id=123&status=complete
```

- Warning: Example code, generally a good hook should provide authentication method.

That way your server can interpret that information as

> order with id 123 has been completed

That was a basic implementation.

Other easier analogy is:

> a user accessing a url and input a form and press submit. To which url the data is sent, that url can also be called hook.

Answer (score 1):

Basically they are telling you to implement a service that they would call when a transaction ocurred successfully, instead of you going to them.

Comment: So, when they call our service, how to update the page?

Comment: Well  you could implement websocket for bilateral communication and update the page once they call your service